# How to implement a generic method given a type?

Tags: java, generics

I have a java interface,like this:

```
public interface ScheduleControllerInterface {

    <T extends ScheduleAddUpdateDTO> CommonResult<String> commit(@Valid T commitDTO);
}
```

now,i want to implement this interface,and given a type to generic type,like this:

```
public class CarScheduleController implements ScheduleControllerInterface {

    @Override
    public CommonResult<String> commit(CarScheduleDTO commitDTO) {
        carSchedule.commitSchedule(commitDTO);
        return CommonResult.success();
    }
}
```

but when i try it,it called i don't have override the method,My interface have a lot of generic method , i want to implements it,What can i do?

[the table design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ne3hv.jpg)

Comment: The interface requires that the method takes a generic parameter. What about making your interface parameterized instead of the method?

Comment: @matt My interface has other generic method,
 ``` <T extends ScheduleInfoVO> CommonResult<T> getSchedule(String scheduleCode); 
<T extends ScheduleAddUpdateDTO> CommonResult<String> confirm(T confirmDTO); ``` 
I can't making a generic interface

Comment: I don't understand why you need a generic parameter for your method. Why would you have an interface that uses a concrete "getSchedule" class, but a generic or different class for "commit"? If you want the methods to be concrete make the `T` at the class level.

Comment: @matt hello,matt,schedule have 8 subclass,it has differents params and save these into different tables,and ScheduleControllerInterface  is all 8 class'parent interface,i want to control all subclass allow the rule,and get different class that is Common params class 's sub class into commit method,You can see this scene in my reply to matt's answer.

Comment: @matt the "getSchedule" method has a param is all subclass will generate in commit,but  it will return different class by call the method.

Comment: How about `ScheduleControlledInterface<T, V>` Then each method has it's own parameter that is set when you create the implementation. If the implementation only wokrs for one type of the generic, then you should say that at the interface definition.

Comment: @matt I think you are right,I will try to extra some same type param.And i will found whether I can implement it that I don't need more Type params for interface

Answer (score 6):

You cannot "specialize" a generic in Java (like you would in C++). A generic method has to remain generic and you cannot replace generic type parameters with concrete types.

What you could do is not making your method generic, but your interface generic and then implement the interface while providing a concrete type argument to the generic type parameter:

```
public interface ScheduleControllerInterface<T extends ScheduleAddUpdateDTO> {
  CommonResult<String> commit(@Valid T commitDTO);
}

public class CarScheduleController implements ScheduleControllerInterface<CarScheduleDTO> {
    @Override
    public CommonResult<String> commit(CarScheduleDTO commitDTO) {
        carSchedule.commitSchedule(commitDTO);
        return CommonResult.success();
    }
}
```

Comment: My interface has other generic method,
```
    <T extends ScheduleInfoVO> CommonResult<T> getSchedule(String scheduleCode);

    <T extends ScheduleAddUpdateDTO> CommonResult<String> confirm(T confirmDTO);
```
i can't making generic interface,am I only allowed to give up the generic method,and change  the generic method to polymorphism？

Comment: @zhili if your interface has other generic methods that would break if you would add a generic parameter, then your interface might be doing too much or has other design flaws. Consider creating a second interface for that use case.

Comment: @QBrute,hello,the Schedule has commit,delete,delete,confirm  method,it has different params.and The Schedule has subClass like car,hotel,meals... if i create other generic interface Then I can't identify these methods as Schedule's methods.Am I only allowed to give up the generic method,and change the generic method to polymorphism？

Comment: @zhili if you require multiple independent concrete types (but still need them to be generic), you could split your interface into separate interfaces and implement each with a different concrete type in your class.

Comment: @knittl hello,knittl,I have a lot of method,If i split the interface into separate interfaces,i will implements a lot of interfaces, and i can't control my colleagues can implements this  interfaces,I think the interface is the rule,and all sub class must in the rule,and the generic type is rule the param must is the given type's sub type,then i will get the common params

Comment: @knittl  I already konw i will have 8 subclass for schedule,and the schedule has common methed,like commit,confirm,getDetail,delete,cancel..,if i split this method to diffrent interface,I can't konw all the sub type is allow the rule and implementa all the interface.I think I'm off on my understanding of generics, I should be using polymorphism to define these methods and then forcing cast to the type needed by the subclass. I don't want subclasses to force cast, so I'm defining the interface methods using generics.If I can't do this,i think i will use polymorphism to figuer out it.

Comment: @zhili your design seems off. Why do you have an interface with generic methods and each method requires a different type? Why does `carSchedule#commitSchedule` require a concrete type and is not generic itself? I wouldn't really recommend it, but you could make your interface generic with 8 type parameters (`ScheduleControllerInterface<COMMIT, CONFIRM, DETAIL, DELETE, CANCEL>`) – implementing it allows you to "pin" all types. Why do you have so many subclasses? Why do you have an interface if your implementers don't really have anything in common?

Comment: @knittl the all subClass is schedule,the schedule has some common property,such as scheduleCode,groupCode,orders,cooperater,but like car,it have different property defined about car info,hotel like this.and the all sub class has same methods,so I need different params.I think you gaven the 8 type parameters can resolve my problem.Also,I will paste a image to show the table design in qustion.You can see the image and know why i design like this.

Answer (score -2):

In various programming languages, the implementation of generic methods can differ. However, the concept generally remains the same - to create a method that can operate on different types of data without specifying the actual type until it's used.

Here's a basic example in Java:

```
public class GenericMethodExample {

// This is a generic method that works with any type T
public <T> void printArray(T[] array) {
    for (T element : array) {
        System.out.print(element + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    GenericMethodExample example = new GenericMethodExample();

    // Example with Integer array
    Integer[] intArray = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    example.printArray(intArray);

    // Example with String array
    String[] stringArray = { "apple", "orange", "banana" };
    example.printArray(stringArray);
} }
```

In this example:

The printArray method is generic and uses the placeholder .
It accepts an array of any type T and prints its elements.
The main method demonstrates how to use this generic method with both Integer and String arrays.

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

apple orange banana

Comment: This does not answer the question. The question is not about what a generic method is, but how to "specialize" a generic method (i.e. pin its type to a single concrete type)